# Restrict this regex to "edu", top-level domain

Tags: regex

I have this regex that checks the validity of an email address

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

I want to tweak it so it ensures the email address entered is an .edu account.

PS - It's not for homework, I swear.

Comment: try edu$ instead of `([A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

Comment: For the love of `$dmr` don't attempt to use regex to validate email addresses.

Comment: @tripleee: Acually, this is one time where it acually is useful: The OP wants to ensure it's an `edu` domain adress. Well ok, could've used the language variant of `endsWith` instead...

Comment: Then the correct regex is simply just `\.edu$` and the chaff before that is superfluous.  It currently fails on addresses such as `me+plus@example.edu` but it's futile to enumerate all the failure cases because the approach is basically flawed.  This really deserves a standard answer just like the "don't use regex to parse HTML" boilerplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.[Ee][Dd][Uu]$/;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change `([A-Za-z]{2,4})` into `[Ee][Dd][Uu]`.

Comment: It might be useful to do the entire regular expression case insensitive, to make it more readable. Just add an `i` at the end: `var reg = /<expression>/i`

Answer (score 2):

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.(edu)$/i;
```